Are epochs the same as data duplication?
Epochs, the number of times training is repeated on the original data, are absolutely necessary for neural networks where there are often many more parameters than original instances.
What is the methodological status of using epochs for other ML methods with many parameters? Are they used for (what I would call) class techniques like Random Forests?
That is, why aren't epochs used for say plain old logistic regression or decision trees? Why isn't more than each additional epoch just considered data augmentation but with identical instances? I feel like any statistician would get sick to their stomach if repeating data was suggested to decrease bias. An ML modeler has no compunction against increasing epochs indefinitely until the training/test accuracy ratio starts getting bad (or maybe not even then!).
So

is it OK to use epochs (essential duplicating instances) with traditional prediction models (as long as you take into account overfitting?
and on the other side, should -one- epoch be the standard for NN training or rather, aren't there all sorts of statistical problems with duplicating data as an augmentation technique?

Since logistic regression is in a sense the simplest neural network, is there a way in that algorithm to show how the approximation on a set of data is different from an approximation on a single extra repetition of the data?

You're begging the question. Remember why they use multiple epochs: the gradient-based approximations take small steps in the direction of the true solution. This is different from a count-based technique like Good–Turing estimation where doubling the data would indeed break the method by altering counts. (Also. Who said you don't use multiple epochs to estimate a logistic regression?)

The premise of the question is wrong: "epoch" does not simply amount to duplicating data.

@Firebug Can you elaborate? Is it not duplicating at all? Or are there additional things that happen in addition to data duplication? Or something else?

It's not duplicating at all

@Firebug Can you elaborate in an answer?

Sycorax already explained what is an epoch, and it is clear that iterated optimization procedures can reuse data, which is not the same as duplicating data.

Instead of editing to add an additional question after you've already received an answer, please ask a new question instead.

First, let's focus on why neural networks train for multiple epochs in the first palce. Making multiple passes over the data in NNs is purely a matter of optimization -- it can take many updates to improve the fit of the model to the data/get adequate out-of-sample prediction quality.
Goodfellow et al. discuss this in the Deep Learning chapter on optimization. On page 277, they write:

An interesting motivation for minibatch stochastic gradient descent is that it follows the gradient of the true generalization error (equation 8.2) as long as no examples are repeated. Most implementations of minibatch stochastic gradient descent shuffe the dataset once and then pass through it multiple times. On the first pass, each minibatch is used to compute an unbiased estimate of the true generalization error. On the second pass, the estimate becomes biased because it is formed by resampling values that have already been used, rather than obtaining new fair samples from the data-generating distribution.

That said, the core bargain in every scenario with multiple passes is that even though you're increasing the model's bias, as long as you get a greater improvement in model fit, then you're better off. In other words, if the model is getting better at making predictions, then the increased bias isn't really harming you. Goodfellow et al. continue:

Nonetheless, it is usually best to make several passes through the training set, unless the training set is extremely large. When multiple such epochs are used, only the first epoch follows the unbiased gradient of the generalization error, but of course, the additional epochs usually provide enough beneﬁt due to decreased training error to oﬀset the harm they cause by increasing the gap between training error and test error.

Second, let's discuss other methods.

You mention random forest specifically as a point of contrast with making multiple passes over the data. However, a random forest bootstraps the training data when constructing each tree. So, in aggregate, the forest is composed of multiple trees, and among all trees the entire dataset is repeated multiple times.

The optimal parameters for logistic regression are only computed iteratively, so logistic regression is also trained in multiple epochs.

And if you have a really large OLS problem, too large to use standard decomposition techniques, then it can also be trained in the minibatch gradient descent fashion in multiple epochs.


For these reasons, I don’t agree with the characterization that multiple passes over the data are duplicating the data in any of these scenarios.

is it OK to use epochs (essential duplicating instances) with traditional prediction models (as long as you take into account overfitting?

Sure, making multiple passes over the data is fine, but you don't want to overfit. This is addressed in the Goodfellow book.

and on the other side, should -one- epoch be the standard for NN training or rather, aren't there all sorts of statistical problems with duplicating data as an augmentation technique?

No, restricting NNs to a single epoch is not good practice because it will tend to underfit the data.

Since logistic regression is in a sense the simplest neural network, is there a way in that algorithm to show how the approximation on a set of data is different from an approximation on a single extra repetition of the data?

Duplicating the data won't change the coefficient estimates, but it will change their standard errors and other inferential statistics.

Re logistic regression... are you saying that the iterative approximation technique (Newton-Raphson?) used to compute the parameters is analogous to/kinda/pretty much, exactly gradient descent in a neural network -and- that each iteration is essentially an epoch? My impression is that one epoch in NN training is optimizing for the entire training set once, and  Newton-Raphson for LogReg is like one epoch, only looking at the original data once.

Yeah, making a pass over all the training data to update the NN parameters is an epoch. And logistic regression estimation techniques update the parameters by looking at all of the training data -- so it is also an epoch. And both methods are iterative optimization. You can even estimate a logistic regression using minibatch gradient descent, just as you would with a neural network (though you usually wouldn't unless you have enormous data).

So to make clear, is it the case that n epochs on one data set does not result in the same as one epoch on n copies of that one data set? And if so (that seems to be what you and Firebug are saying, how exactly do they differ?

If I understand your question correctly, then it’s asked & answered here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242004/why-do-neural-network-researchers-care-about-epochs?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C39.0991

Though I take it that the answer is 'Obviously no, an extra epoch does not give the same solution as an extra set of (identical) data' it is still not obvious to me, even with the suggested link, how the solutions differ. Selection with replacement seems awfully close to duplication. Since -linear- regression obviously distinguishes the two (no iterative approximation needed, and duplicate data gives an obviously different solution). For an approximation algorithm how would duplicate data interact with the selection process (with our without replacement)?

The link shows that training with epochs converges faster than just resampling from the training data. I feel that I've fully and completely answered the original question in your post. If you have additional questions, such as the one you added with your recent edit, you should ask them in a new thread. I don't know why you're still struggling to distinguish duplicating data with making multiple passes over a data set, so I don't know what else I can say to try to convince you that they are different.

Your answer has helped me immensely (likewise your linked question) but I am still at a stage of understanding -before- your similar question. My comment and edit might lead to someone else who can provide an answer that gets me over the edge.
